# Apache Strimzi Kafka Bridge implementation

Tags: apache-kafka, strimzi

This is a very generic question to the community out there, especially the Kafka Strimzi Bridge folks if they are reading this.

I am trying to implement their Apache Kafka HTTP Bridge as a POC for something. The documentation is very very poor and doesn't provide any assistance. I really just need to know how do you publish and consume messages off Kafka topic using the bridge. I have started the bridge but do not know anything beyond that as the documentation lacks basic examples.

Comment: I've not used it, but what exactly are you trying? The request paths and examples seem well documented to me https://strimzi.io/docs/bridge/latest/#_paths

Answer (score 3):

Which version of the bridge are you using?
The bridge documentation about exposed API is at the following link for the latest 0.14.0 version:
https://strimzi.io/docs/bridge/latest/

You can also find an overall description of the bridge itself and a quick start guide in the Strimzi documentation here:
https://strimzi.io/docs/latest/#kafka-bridge-concepts-str

Are you using it on Kubernetes deploying the Apache Kafka cluster with Strimzi cluster operator as well or as stand-alone?

If you need more help you can join our #strimzi channel on CNCF Slack workspace of course.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am a member on the Slack workspace since a while. I did not see any members in there to ask this question. I am deploying this on a EC2 instance. All I really need is a simple example of using the bridge. I tried multiple ways of publishing a message using curl on the HTTP port in the application properties file. The server doesnt seem to acknowledge any. The entire documentation is based off Kubernetes.

Comment: Can you provide me more details? Is the port reachable from the outside so are you able to establish a TCP connection at least? Have you tried to reach the /topics/{topicname} endpoint for publishing? Did you get any response from the bridge, something in the log? What do you mean by "The server doesnt seem to acknowledge any". Where is the Kafka cluster running? You mentioned Kubernetes, are you using it with Strimzi cluster operator for deploying the Kafka cluster as well? Can you provide the example you are using for publishing?

Comment: Sorry for being elusive. I was responding from my phone. Here are my issues.

Comment: Sorry Nick, where are the issues? I cannot see anything :-)

Comment: Here are my issues. 
1) I started the bridge. I call that as a server that's providing the service.
2) I am able to use the /GET Api using POSTMAN or curl in general and get responses from the server 
3) I am unable to post messages on the topic using POST /topics/<topic>. I am using plain old Kafka. I am able to run Kafka Producers and Consumers directly that can consume messages confirming that Kafka setup is correct.
4) I just need a small payload (any payload) or rather the format of posting a message. 
Can this bridge be used for streaming or as a simple request/response service?.

Comment: The links above provide you what you need. Format of the API and a getting started guide for interacting with the bridge.

Comment: I will try that. Thanks for the info. I sent you a linkedin connection as well.

Comment: The example curl is in the doc: https://strimzi.io/docs/latest/#proc-producing-messages-from-bridge-topics-partitions-kafka-bridge-quickstart

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I was able to produce and consume using the API. However, it seems that the API only allows a pull kind of architecture where an external client subscribes to a topic (through the bridge) and receives all messages from the topic, if any. Is there a way for a long lived/websockets kind of connectivity where the client connection stays open until they explicitly terminate it so that they don't have to repeatedly make HTTP calls that could return empty responses?.

Comment: No there is no way for that. The HTTP bridge purpose is to translate HTTP to Kafka protocol but providing the same behavior as a native Kafka client where you need to do a poll loop for getting messages. The other way is using the AMQP protocol support of the bridge but it's for now just a POC.